# For which $a$ do the decimal expansions of $\frac{1}{2^a}$ and $\frac{1}{3^a}$ not "overlap"?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

So I had a confusing question that I will completely rephrase here.

When two decimal numbers don't *overlap*, then when we add them together we dropping down the digits would give the answer. For example, $1.025 + 0.2$ is $1.225$. The ones, tenths, hundredths, and thousandths digits are the same as in the addends. But $1.25+1.35$ is $2.6$ and the ones and tens of the sum isn't the same as the ones in the summands.

So I was wondering:

> For which $a$ does $\dfrac{1}{2^a}$ and $\dfrac{1}{3^a}$ not overlap?
>
> Is there an inequality we could make to find $a$?

Comment: I still think there are _much_ better ways of describing overlap: Two numbers overlap when there is some digit position where they are both non-zero. Trying to explain this by how one would add them together is entirely confusing. Also, it would've been better if you had edited your [original post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4565873/when-the-digits-dont-overlap?noredirect=1#comment9606877_4565873) rather than deleting it and making a new one.

Comment: I agree with Arthur. It also makes you farther from the *Curious* badge.

Comment: I don't understand what the adding has to do with anything.  The example with $1.025$ and $0.2$ works only as you are adding positions that are 0 in one or the other of *every* place.  $1.2345$ and $6.7891$ also don't overlap but adding them together to get $8.0236$ is.... well, I have no idea what point you are trying to make.

Comment: $1.96 + 2.85= 4.91$ and the tens place is the same.  IS this "overlapping".  Or do you mean *all* positions must match.  But if *all* positions must match one or the other, that must mean that in every position on or the other is equal to $0$.  Why not just say that?

Comment: @fleablood They may have become interested in this property when considering the addition of decimal numbers and didn't consider that equivalent formulation.

Comment: Does not overlapping mean one sigit in each colm must be zero? Or just that no column sums to greater than $9$? For instance, is $432+445=877$ an example of overlap or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to "fit" the nonzero digits of $1/2^a$ into the initial nonzero digits of $1/3^a$, it's not going to work. $1/2^a$'s last nonzero digit is always place $a$, while $1/3^a$ has $\lfloor a \log_{10}3 \rfloor\approx a/2.1 < a$ initial zeroes. The other case, where the zero places of $1/3^a$ just so happen to line up with the nonzero places of $1/2^a$ is a little more tricky to prove can't happen, but I would be astonished if there is any such $a$.

We can however use the previous result to find how big $b$ needs to be such that $1/2^a$ fits in the initial zeroes of $1/3^b$: $b = \lceil a \log_{3}10 \rceil$. That said, it may not be the smallest such $b$ if there is the kind of coincidental overlap of zeroes mentioned before. This still seems unlikely, though I will note that $1/2^8$ and $1/3^9$ are only one digit off. At the very least, since the last 3 digits of $1/2^a$ are always $...625$ or $...125$, you would need a $b$ such that $1/3^b$ has three zeroes after its first nonzero digit, and I'm not sure of a way to find those in general without numeric computation.

EDIT: I did find numerically that $(a, b) = (3332, 6976)$ has no overlap through the above mechanism. Starting at decimal place $3325$, $1/2^a = ...56640625000000...$ and $1/3^b = ...00004000617917...$. So it's not impossible, but finding them is quite tricky.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac 1{2^a}$ terminates after $a$ decimal places.  About $\log_{10} 2 \cdot a \approx 0.301a$ of those are zero at the start, but that doesn't help us.  $\frac 1{3^a}$ has about $\log_{10}3 \cdot a \approx 0.477a$ zeros at the start, so there are about
$0.523a$ digits of potential overlap.  You need one of the two decimals to have a $0$ in every one of those positions.  I checked in a spreadsheet up to $a=17$ and there are none that are even close.  I don't think a spreadsheet has the accuracy to go higher but I would be very surprised if there were any at all.  It would be easy to write a Python program to check much higher as it has arbitrary precision integers built in.